# What are the differences between these two racket functions in terms of speed/efficiency?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

```
(define (myminus x y)
  (cond ((zero? y) x)
        (else (sub1 (myminus x (sub1 y))))))

(define (myminus_v2 x y)
  (cond ((zero? y) x)
        (else (myminus_v2 (sub1 x) (sub1 y)))))
```

Please comment on the differences between these functions in terms of how
much memory is required on the stack for each recursive call. Also, which version might
you expect to be faster, and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should both have a number of steps proportional to y.

The second one is a tail call meaning the interpreter can do a tail elimination meaning it takes up a constant space on the stack whereas in the first the size of the stack is proportional to Y.

Comment: There is no need to wrap it. `racket` does tail call optimization on outer functions just fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, so the first doesn't count as tail recursion because the recursive call is nested within a separate function?

Comment: @user2253489 Yes. A tail call is when the recursive call is on the tail position. In scheme the arguments to a function are evaluated before the function is invoked, so the theory is that if the recursive call is the last thing to be done in that code block, you can just overwrite the old variables on the stack with the new call values and jump back (GOTO) the beginning of the code block.

Answer (score 2):

`myminus` creates `y` continuations to `sub1` what the recursion evaluates to. This means you can exhaust rackets memory limit making the program fail. In my trials even as little as 10 million will not succeed with the standard 128MB limit in *DrRacket*.

`myminus_v2` is `tail recursive` and since `racket` have same properties as what `scheme` requires, that tail calls are to be optimized to a goto and not grow the stack, y can be any size, i.e. only your available memory and processing power is the limit to the size.

Your procedures are fine examples of [peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_arithmetic).

Comment: Racket supports deep recursion, so the first one won't get a special "stack overflow" error, it'll just run out of memory. The techniques used to implement continuations typically give you deep recursion for free.

Comment: @RyanCulpepper You're right. I've seen it slurp in all memory several times and never a stack overflow. updated.